# File gets deleted on Linux but not on Windows

Tags: java, linux

So I have this program in Java, where I make a file, write to it and save it.
But after the program finishes it's job, I want it to delete the file it created.

Here is the code with which I make the file and delete it:

```
RandomAccessFile file = null;
file = new RandomAccessFile("myFile.zip", "rw");
file.write(buffer,0,read);
file.close();
File file = new File("myFile.zip");
file.delete();
```

It cannot be related to how Windows and Linux use their file paths ( \  or /) as I don't really specify it other than showing it to be at the root of my project.

So what might be the case in this situation?

Comment: Make sure the file exists by calling `file.exists()`. If you get `false` in Windows you know there's something wrong with the path. Then try printing the absolute path with `file.getAbsolutePath()`.

Comment: By the way, looking at your code, there is no indication that the file gets actually created since you don't write anything to it. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: No I do write into it, I just did not show it here, my fault, will edit post just in case. Also, will give your suggestion a try.

Comment: Allright, reporting back. The file absolute path is printed out and it matches where the file is located nicely. The file exists too according to file.exists() but it just does not delete it.

Comment: Well, that code wont compile as you are defining 'file' twice. Can you provide a compilable short snippet that reproduces the issue ?

Comment: Check the result of delete. If it is `false`, maybe there's an outside problem.

Comment: It is true, Exception in catch does not give anything too. It just does not delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Windows notices the open file handle and refuses to delete the open file.  That's a policy in Windows.  Files which are open do not disappear.  The process holding the open file handle can rely on that the file will stay.

Linux has a different policy.  There a file can be deleted from all directories (yes, it can be in more than one when it is hard linked), even if a process still has an open handle on it.  The file itself will then not be removed from the disk.  The process using the open handle can still process the file, make it grow, shrink it, write to it, read from it.  But after the handle gets closed, the file gets removed automatically by the file system.

These different policies of the to OSes you are using are the reason for your observation.

Comment: So loading the file into file variable makes Windows consider it as opened allready? By variable I mean File file = new File("myFile.zip");

Comment: No.  I guess you have another open file handle somewhere.

Comment: It is possible that the `.close()` returns before the closing actually takes place, in network file systems.  In some cases a small delay solves the issue.

Comment: Nop, nothing works, added the delete thing in front of my program and at the end, nothing will delete it.

Comment: Did you consider that some other process might have an open file handle on your file?

Comment: Yes, I made everything = with null that could use the file. Did not do much even then.

Comment: But I will give it another look because when I made a new program that only does the delete part, then it works.

Comment: I'm not talking about other variables (which can be set to `null` or similar).  I'm talking about other _processes_ which could still be in the middle of writing to or reading from the file.  Did you double-check on those?  Maybe copy your file to a new name and try again with that name.  Have you tried deleting your file with normal Windows means like the file manager?

Comment: Yes it will delete in normal ways. The idea is that the file that gets created is just a temporary .zip file from which I get some info from Central Directory and then I delete it. The program it self is not supposed to leave clutter of files behind it.

Comment: This is very strange. Have you tried a different machine, different path, etc?